# Router unable to find component

Tags: angular6

I have defined a route in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
//question-details;question-id=a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7
  {
    path:'question-details;question-id=:id',
    component:QuestionDetailsComponent
  }


@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], //
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers:[]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

The route should get activated when an `html` button is clicked.

```
<button  [routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink,{'question-id':question['question-id']}]" id="{{'show-more-button-'+(i+1)}}" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button>
```

`questionDetailRouterLink` is defined as

```
export var QUESTION_DETAIL_ROUTER_LINK = '/question-details';
questionDetailRouterLink = QUESTION_DETAIL_ROUTER_LINK
```

When the button is clicked, the `url` in the browser changes to `localhost:9000/question-details;question-id=a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7`

But `QuestionDetailsComponent` is not shown. What am I doing wrong?

The `RouterModule` is defined as

```
app.module.ts

imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can't use query params (denoted by `?`) or path parameters (denoted by `;`) to specify a full route i.e. I can't do the following as then the route is not able to find the component

```
path:'question-details?question-id=:id',   //question-details?question-id=a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7 - qusetion id is a query parameter
path:'question-details;question-id=:id', //question-details;question-id=a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7 - question id is a path parameter
```

I had to keep the route only till question-details and then extract query or path parameters(whatever I am using) in the component

```
{
    path:'question-details',
    component:QuestionDetailsComponent
  }
```

I am passing the `question-id` as path param in html - `<button  [routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink, {'question-id':question['question-id']}]" id="{{'show-more-button-'+(i+1)}}" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button>`

and in the component, got the path params by calling `this.question_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("question-id");//question-details;question-id=:id'`

In summary, I can pass additional data to a route either as path parameter or query parameter but I can't use that to match/resolve a route. These parameters could be accessed in the component by calling respective properties.

Eg. passing both path parameter and query parameter to a routerlink

```
<button  [routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink, {'question-id':question['question-id']}]" [queryParams]="{'query1':'value1'}"  id="{{'show-more-button-'+(i+1)}}" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button>
```

accessing them in the respective component

```
console.log("path params are :"+this.route.snapshot.paramMap);
    console.log("query params are :"+this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap);
```

But route path is still

```
{
        path:'question-details',
        component:QuestionDetailsComponent
      }
```

the above will print the following

```
path params are : 
ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}
keys: (...)
params: {question-id: "a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7"}
__proto__: Object
question-details.component.ts:96 query params are : 
ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}
keys: (...)
params: {query1: "value1"}
__proto__: Object
```

Which left me with question what does `id` mean in `path: 'hero/:id'`. It seems `id` would have the value  between `hero/` and the first `;` or `?` in the route. If the route is `hero/my-hero/42?name=Manu` or `hero/my-hero/42;name=Manu` or `hero/my-hero/42;age=40?name=Manu` then `id` in all the three would be `my-hero/42` and the route will match any route which is `hero/<something here>` (not sure about this though)

this is a brilliant article about URLs - https://skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/

Answer (score 3):

In angular 6,Try this code ..

In html part:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/question-details/question-id']" mat-icon-button color="primary" [queryParams]="{question-id: id}">click here</a>
```

in Routing ts:

```
{
  path:'question-details/question-id',
  component:QuestionDetailsComponent
}
```

Comment: Woudn't the route then become `/question-details/queston-id`? My `route` is `/question-details?question-id=a5551f5d-e8c6-4b1a-a7e2-6c878de291c7`, not `question-details/question-id?question-id=...`

Comment: For that you just need to change the URL from ```/question-details/queston-id```  to  ```/question-details``` in router component and also set the same URL in  HTML part

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in HTML

```
    <button class="btn btn-info" [routerLink]="['/question-details']" [queryParams]="{question-id:id}">Show More</button>
```

In routing module

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { QuestionDetailsComponent } from 'ComponentPath';

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'question-details', component:QuestionDetailsComponent },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: but `questionDetailRouterLink` is equal to `'/question-details'`. The following isn't working unfortunately - ` <button  [routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink]" [queryParams]="{'question-id':question['question-id']}" id="{{'show-more-button-'+(i+1)}}" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Show more</button>`

Comment: can you have your app-routing.module.ts here. if you want like the above means you have to change the path in app-routing.module.ts like {path: questionDetailRouterLink, component:QuestionDetailsComponent }